# mysql parent/child join

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a mysql query that combines the data from two tables. Where prijzen2.Kortinggroep is parent and Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Kortinggroep child.

Table1: prijzen2

```
Relatie;Prijsgroep;Kortinggroep;Tarief_code;Waardefunctie;Waarde;Ingangsdatum;Einddatum;Omschrijving
13073; 13073 ;; 3250174; Price per price unit; 0.98 ;;; Black hose guided bend 14-17mm 3250174
13073; 13073 ;; 3250175; Price per price unit; 1.2 ;;; Black hose guided bend 18-23mm 3250175
13008; HJ; 102201; Discount%; 28; 21-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13551; 13551; 102201; Discount%; 28; 08-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13669; 13669; 102201; Discount%; 28; 10-01-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13189; 13189; 102203; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13086; 13086; 102203; Discount%; 35 ;;; Inventum water heaters
```

A child table with extra data: Kortingsgroepen_webshop

```
Kortinggroep;Tarief_code
102201;07.02.26.631
102201;07.02.26.634
102201;07.02.86.632
102201;07.02.10.636
102201;07.02.26.031
102203;40140520_1
102203;40221020_1
102203;40221004_1
102203;40141020_1
102203;40141004_1
102203;40231020_1
102203;40231004_1
102203;40141520_1
102203;40231520_1
102203;40122020
102203;15198706_1
102203;15201000_1
102203;1240536
102203;1240560
102203;42185006
102203;43188010
102203;44182015
102203;41183116
102203;44182132
102203;48181535
102203;41183020
102203;42185024
102203;43188024
102203;44182030
102203;44042033
102203;44042063
102203;43048033
102203;43048063
102203;35220080
102203;15036080
102203;35220050
102203;35220120
102203;35220154
102203;35220124
102203;35220150
102203;35220100
```

Need result with a query:

```
Relatie;Prijsgroep;Kortinggroep;Tarief_code;Waardefunctie;Waarde;Ingangsdatum;Einddatum;Omschrijving
13073; 13073 ;; 3250174; Price per price unit; 0.98 ;;; Black hose guided bend 14-17mm 3250174
13073; 13073 ;; 3250175; Price per price unit; 1.2 ;;; Black hose guided bend 18-23mm 3250175
13008; HJ; 102201; 07.02.26.631; Discount%; 28; 21-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13008; HJ; 102201; 07.02.26.634; Discount%; 28; 21-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13008; HJ; 102201; 07.02.86.632; Discount%; 28; 21-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13008; HJ; 102201; 07.02.10.636; Discount%; 28; 21-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13008; HJ; 102201; 07.02.26.031; Discount%; 28; 21-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13551; 13551; 102201; 07.02.26.631; Discount%; 28; 08-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13551; 13551; 102201; 07.02.26.634; Discount%; 28; 08-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13551; 13551; 102201; 07.02.86.632; Discount%; 28; 08-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13551; 13551; 102201; 07.02.10.636; Discount%; 28; 08-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13551; 13551; 102201; 07.02.26.031; Discount%; 28; 08-02-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13669; 13669; 102201; 07.02.26.631; Discount%; 28; 10-01-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13669; 13669; 102201; 07.02.26.634; Discount%; 28; 10-01-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13669; 13669; 102201; 07.02.86.632; Discount%; 28; 10-01-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13669; 13669; 102201; 07.02.10.636; Discount%; 28; 10-01-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13669; 13669; 102201; 07.02.26.031; Discount%; 28; 10-01-17 ;; Daalderop boilers
13189; 13189; 102203; 40140520_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 40221020_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 40221004_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 40141020_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 40141004_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 40231020_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 40231004_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 40141520_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 40231520_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 40122020; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 15198706_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 15201000_1; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 1240536; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 1240560; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 42185006; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 43188010; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 44182015; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 41183116; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 44182132; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 48181535; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 41183020; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 42185024; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 43188024; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 44182030; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 44042033; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 44042063; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 43048033; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 43048063; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 35220080; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 15036080; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 35220050; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Inventum water heaters
13189; 13189; 102203; 35220120; Discount%; 27.5 ;;; Invent
```

With this query I get almost the desired result. Both the Tarief_code columns need to be merged but I can not manage it. Does anyone have any tips?

The query that i have for now is :

```
SELECT
prijzen2.Relatie,
prijzen2.Prijsgroep,
Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Kortinggroep,
Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Tarief_code,
prijzen2.Tarief_code,
prijzen2.Waardefunctie,
prijzen2.Waarde
FROM
prijzen2
LEFT JOIN Kortingsgroepen_webshop
ON Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Kortinggroep=prijzen2.Kortinggroep
```

Fixed bij this query:

```
SELECT
prijzen2.Relatie,
prijzen2.Prijsgroep,
Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Kortinggroep,
COALESCE( Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Tarief_code, prijzen2.Tarief_code) AS Tarief_code,
prijzen2.Waardefunctie,
prijzen2.Waarde
FROM
prijzen2
LEFT JOIN Kortingsgroepen_webshop
ON Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Kortinggroep=prijzen2.Kortinggroep
```

Comment: "With this query I get almost the desired result. Both the Tarief_code columns need to be merged but I can not manage it. Does anyone have any tips?" Wait what do you mean with merged by the way? Besidse if i look to your example data and query it should already give you the correct results .. i geuss i was too focused because you said parent/child relations..

Answer (score 0):

If by merge you mean to get this as one field:

```
07.02.26.631 Discount%
```

...then you can use CONCAT() like so:

```
SELECT
prijzen2.Relatie,
prijzen2.Prijsgroep,
Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Kortinggroep,
CONCAT(Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Tarief_code, " ", prijzen2.Tarief_code) as 'Tarief_code',
prijzen2.Waardefunctie,
prijzen2.Waarde
FROM
prijzen2
LEFT JOIN Kortingsgroepen_webshop
ON Kortingsgroepen_webshop.Kortinggroep=prijzen2.Kortinggroep
```

Comment: Need to be merged after  the result.

Comment: Can you show me an example of the desired result? I am afraid I do not understand what your end goal is.